# Difference between the hole in a torus and the hole in an annulus

Tags: general-topology, terminology

A [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) and an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) are both not [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) surfaces. The manner in which they fail to be simply connected is clearly different; they have "different kinds of holes", so to speak. The hole in the annulus corresponds to a boundary of the surface, the hole in the torus does not.

Is there standard terminology to distinguish the kind of hole in a torus and the kind of hole in an annulus?

Comment: You're looking for the concept of [homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)).

Comment: Topologists do not speak in terms of "holes." But the difference between the two surfaces is that one (the annulus) has homology generated by a separating loop, while the other )torus) has homology generated by two nonseparating loops.